# How to log unzipped gzip content using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient

I'm using Spring Boot (ver. 3.1.1) RestTemplate which is configured to use Apache `org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient` (ver. 5.2.1) like this

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    //we make Rest Template using HTTP client to be able to turn logging on
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}
```

I have turned the Logback logging like this

```
<logger name="org.apache.hc.client5.http" level="debug"/>
```

And when I check the logs after I send a request, I can see the response is being compressed by gzip, so the incoming payload is unreadable:

```
... headers omitted for brevity
2023-06-180 10:23:54.222 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "AY[0xffffffce][0x19][0xffffffd5][0xffffffc6][0xffffff8f]hFY[0x3]H[0xffffff9e]3[0xffffff8a][0x1][0xfffffffa]*{[0xffffff9f]V[0xffffffe3]|[0xffffffba][0xffffffb5]O'[0x1e][0xffffffcb][0xffffffff]w[0xffffffc1][0xffffffe7][0x7f][0xfffffffe][0x1f][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffff][0xffffffff][0x3][0x0][0xffffffcd][0xffffff89][0xfffffff0][0xffffffd7][0x3][0xffffffd5][0x3][0x0][\r][\n]"
```

Is it possible to log the response body after it is unzipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apache HTTP client will log the data as it is sent/received. That's why it is called wire logging.

If you want to log the payload un compressed you have to do it yourself in your code.